# Expressjs domain redirect not work on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

I'm learning Nodejs and trying to depoly OpenShift,

I use express and it was work on OpenShift util I add this code,

```
//redirect domain to www.domain
app.all(/.*/, function(req, res, next) {
    var host = req.header("host");
    if (host.match(/^www\..*/i)) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.redirect(301, "http://www." + host);
    }
});
```

But it's work on my localhost , 
I just want to redirect `mydomain.biz` to `www.mydomain.biz`

thank you very much

Comment: I dont konw why 'req.header("host")' was undefined . I tried req.hostname and req.originalUrl , they were undefined too

Answer (score 1):

Please console.log `req.header("host")` on openshift, it must macth regex `/^www\..*/i`.

Comment: it was `undefined` , but why ?
I tried `req.hostname` and `req.originalUrl` , they were `undefined` too

Comment: Are you sure about it?If req.header('host') is undefined, host.match will throw an error "cann't read match of undefined".